# Is there any OpenGL operations cost GPU resource significantly?

Tags: opengl, gpu, nvidia

The situation I met is that I run several OpenGL programs concurrently on a single server with only one GPU cards. They works fine with the FPS of 60.

But the problem is when I restart one of then, the FPS of the others drop a lot, may to 3X or even 1X

If I restart 2 or more at the same time, it can be worse, FPS can be only single-digit

I'm wondering is there any OpenGL initialization(create context/setup texture) operation that may cost the GPU resource a lot?

The environment: Linux(Ubuntu 14.04) NVIDIA GTX 770  with X11 window system

Comment: Does performance recover after startup? But yes, init is probably not optimized in the driver at all and might take a long global lock. Also check how you quit your process. Make sure they exit clean and free all their gl contexts manually. Signal based termination might confuse drivers a lot.

Comment: It do recover after startup. And I also find that it the startup cause the FPS drop, since when I newly start another program, the FPS also drops.

Comment: If you want to do some debugging, create a test program that only creates a gl context and renders a clear frame. See if the slowdown happens with launching that one also. I know that some drivers are optimized for a startup phase. Create and compile all shaders once, do bulk static uploads. I could see drivers holding a global lock longer just for that. You could maybe change user space code to render the first frame early and create shaders and textures lazy.

Answer (score 0):

There are indeed some operations that most OpenGL implementations carry out on the CPU. Most notably when sending images to the GPU any necessary format conversions (i.e. if the image data is not yet in a format that can be processed by the GPU) are done on the CPU. Also every OpenGL object that carries bulk data (textures, render buffers, array buffer objects) usually requires a shadow copy in system memory (the GPU memory mostly acts like a cache) and initializing that is a costly operation as well.

Sending bulk data to the GPU consumes bus bandwidth. While this does not really hit the CPU or GPU due to being carried out using DMA transfer, it consumes memory bandwidth on either side thus impacting memory intensive operations on either side.

Comment: Also don't forget shader compilation! A pure CPU operation. Buffer uploads I would think are frequent enough that they are sliced nicely.

Comment: Thanks both of you, I will try to press CPU and memory to see if they effect my OpenGL program.

Comment: @CurtisGuo: Keep in mind that many (older) OpenGL programs make use of outdated programming methods (immediate mode) that are very heavy on the CPU due to function call overhead. To some degree OpenGL, no matter how modern the API features you use, is CPU bound, hence the introduction of Vulkan which sole aim is to get as much of the CPU overhead out of the way as possible, while remaining portable across GPUs.

Comment: @starmole: Thanks reminding me. But in my situation, shader is rarely used.

Comment: @datenwolf It seem not the CPU, I have tried to use 1000 threads to occupy all the cpu, while the FPS of the program only drops less than 5